# Rails + MongoDB: How to find out how what's the position of current record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, nosql

Here's a query for fetching a record from MongoDB:

```
Article.where({'_id' => { "$gt" => params[:id]}}).sort({:_id => 1}).first
```

Let's say in collection is 10 records and this is the 8th newest. How can I found out that this record is on the position 8 from 10 records in the collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do something like this in Mongo: IDs are randomly-generated hashes and are not guaranteed to be sequential like relational database IDs.

I would instead sort by created_at, since that IS guaranteed to be sequential as long as the field exists. Consider something like this:

```
article = Article.find(params[:id])
next = Article.where({"created_at" => {"$gt" => article.created_at}}).desc(:created_at).first
```